# Как правильно установить DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как ни устанавливаю его - не работает! :( Допустим:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CWServer.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CWServer"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:CWServer.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" 
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="JobService"> <!-- CWServer.ViewModels.JobService -->
    <Grid>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestProperty}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Ничего не выводит...

Ааа все я нашел

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:JobService/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Только почему у меня не выходит использовать более короткую запись???

```
DataContext="{x:Type viewModels:JobService}"
```

Comment: потому что это не короткая запись. DataContext биндится на инстанс (или присваивается). Вы же этой записью присваиваете ТИП класса вьюмодели

Comment: @vitidev а для чего же там такой атрибут существует? Может быть надо другое расширение разметки указать? Или еще что то...

Comment: И кстати а вот этой записью (первой) что создается инстанс чтоли? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: атрибут существует для указания типа. Например можно в стилях TargetType, полезно при биндинге Radio к Enum еще. Да много где, хотя не везде нужно указывать полную запись.

Comment: Да. <viewModels:JobService/> создает инстанс с пустым конструктором и присваивает его DataContext. Из-за необходимости создавать инстанс вьюмодели и передавать в него DataContext устанавливают в коде

Comment: Я имел ввиду не x:Type - это вообще не атрибут, а расширение разметки, а именно DataContext атрибут.

Comment: @vitidev ну вообще это и есть ViewModel... А может и нет... В соседней теме два чувака меня в конец запутали, я уже даже и не знаю... :D

Comment: Это не расширение, а базовый принцип Xaml - задание в xml виде свойств обьекта. DataContext - обычное свойство у контрола, поэтому подпадает по это правило

Comment: Вот http://rghost.ru/6VHR9np7c это пример приложения с MVVM Foundation (чет потерял где я его брал). Посмотрите его внимательно и полностью изучите. Очень сильно поясняет где что куда. За вопросами в чат.

Comment: @vitidev Я даже скажу вам откуда это. Вот [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx). Тоже неплохая статья, но пример мне оттуда скачать не удалось.